# OpenCL Kernel only partly writing to output buffer

Tags: c, opencl

I am reading large integer values from an array that has over a million elements. The values obtained are from a wav file by using the libsndfile library. Now if I do not use the kernel, I can write the original array to my output file and listen to the audio with no issues. However, when i decide to use the kernel to do the exact same thing, it only writes maybe less than a second of the song.

At first, I thought this was a memory issue, so i played around with the buffer sizes and still no luck. Then I thought it could be the loop I am doing in the kernel, I also played around with the loop values to come to the same conclusion (still doesn't work.) I am pretty stumped right now and do not know what to do. Here is my code below. Some of the code below is mine, but the main structure I found online to help me with setting up the kernel.

**At the very bottom of this code, if I change OutputData to Array, I get the exact same audio back. Im pretty sure something is wrong with the kernel and thats why it is not writing to the whole song back.**

I know this code is messy but all you have to do to try and test this code is copy and waste it and simply change the path to an input wav file and output wav file.

Just so the objective is clear, I am going to attempt to modify each value in the wav file, to see what would happen. So far, if I multiply the Output value in the kernel by 2, it distorts it. But again, only lasts for like 1 second and the rest of the clip is empty. Note that both input and output files are the same size.

**My For loop is also looping to do 1.2million iterations because thats the number of items i have in my sample wav file**

```
const char* prog = "__kernel void exchange(__global int *Array, __global int *Output) { for(int j = 0; j < 100000; j++){ for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){ Output[j+i] = (Array[j+i]);}  }  }";

int main() {
// This code executes on the OpenCL host
SNDFILE *sf;
SF_INFO info;
int num_channels;
int num, num_items;
//input and output data
int *Array;
int *OutputData;

int f, sr, c;
int i, j;
FILE *out;

/* Open the WAV file. */
info.format = 0;
sf = sf_open("Yourwavfilepathhere", SFM_READ, &info);
if (sf == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
    perror("Error");
    exit(-1);
}
/* Print some of the info, and figure out how much data to read. */
f = info.frames;
sr = info.samplerate;
int format = info.format;
c = info.channels;
printf("frames=%d\n", f);
printf("samplerate=%d\n", sr);
printf("channels=%d\n", c);
printf("format %i\n", format);
num_items = f*c;
printf("num_items=%d\n", num_items);
/* Allocate space for the data to be read, then read it. */
Array = (int *)malloc(num_items*sizeof(int));
OutputData = (int*)malloc(num_items*sizeof(int));;
num = sf_read_int(sf, Array, num_items);
sf_close(sf);
printf("Read %d items\n", num);

//Time variables for performance execution. Event variable needed for timing constraint 
cl_event someEvent;
cl_ulong start = (cl_ulong)0;
cl_ulong end = (cl_ulong)0;
cl_ulong finalTime = (cl_ulong)0;

//Number of sampling points 
int sampleSize = 100;
float h = 0;

//Coefficient used to multiply the values entering the FIFO buffer implemented inside the kernel
float coefficient = 1 / sampleSize;

//Signal Frequency in Hz
float signalFreq = 10;

//Number of points between 0 and max val (T_Sample)
float freqSample = sampleSize*signalFreq;

//Step = max value or T_Sample. ******Either 1/freqSample or 1/sampleSize for the stepSize******
float stepSize = 1.0 / freqSample;

/*
  This is a different Example
*/


// Use this to check the output of each API call
cl_int status;

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 1: Discover and initialize the platforms
//-----------------------------------------------------

cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;

cl_platform_id *platforms = NULL;

// Use clGetPlatformIDs() to retrieve the number of 
// platforms
status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);

// Allocate enough space for each platform
platforms =
    (cl_platform_id*)malloc(
        numPlatforms*sizeof(cl_platform_id));

// Fill in platforms with clGetPlatformIDs()
status = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms,
    NULL);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 2: Discover and initialize the devices
//----------------------------------------------------- 

cl_uint numDevices = 0;
cl_device_id *devices = NULL;

// Use clGetDeviceIDs() to retrieve the number of 
// devices present
status = clGetDeviceIDs(
    platforms[0],
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,
    0,
    NULL,
    &numDevices);

// Allocate enough space for each device
devices =
    (cl_device_id*)malloc(
        numDevices*sizeof(cl_device_id));

// Fill in devices with clGetDeviceIDs()
status = clGetDeviceIDs(
    platforms[0],
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,
    numDevices,
    devices,
    NULL);


//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 3: Create a context
//----------------------------------------------------- 

cl_context context = NULL;

// Create a context using clCreateContext() and 
// associate it with the devices
context = clCreateContext(
    NULL,
    numDevices,
    devices,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &status);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 4: Create a command queue
//----------------------------------------------------- 

cl_command_queue cmdQueue;

// Create a command queue using clCreateCommandQueue(),
// and associate it with the device you want to execute 
// on
cmdQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(
    context,
    devices[0],
    CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE,
    &status);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 5: Create device buffers
//----------------------------------------------------- 

cl_mem input;
cl_mem output;
cl_float coeff;

input = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    num_items,
    NULL,
    &status);

output = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
    num_items,
    NULL,
    &status);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 6: Write host data to device buffers
//----------------------------------------------------- 

// Use clEnqueueWriteBuffer() to write input array Array to
// the device buffer input
status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(
    cmdQueue,
    input,
    CL_FALSE,
    0,
    num_items,
    Array,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL);

printf("status %i \n", status);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 7: Create and compile the program
//----------------------------------------------------- 

// Create a program using clCreateProgramWithSource()
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(
    context,
    1,
    (const char**)&prog,
    NULL,
    &status);
printf("status %i \n", status);

// Build (compile) the program for the devices with
// clBuildProgram()
status = clBuildProgram(
    program,
    numDevices,
    devices,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 8: Create the kernel
//----------------------------------------------------- 

cl_kernel kernel = NULL;

kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "exchange", &status);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 9: Set the kernel arguments
//----------------------------------------------------- 

// Associate the input and output buffers with the 
// kernel 
// using clSetKernelArg()
status = clSetKernelArg(
    kernel,
    0,
    sizeof(cl_mem),
    &input);
printf("Status %i \n",status);

status |= clSetKernelArg(
    kernel,
    1,
    sizeof(cl_mem),
    &output);


//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 10: Configure the work-item structure
//----------------------------------------------------- 

// Define an index space (global work size) of work 
// items for 
// execution. A workgroup size (local work size) is not 
// required, 
// but can be used.
size_t globalWorkSize[1];
// There are 'elements' work-items 
globalWorkSize[0] = sampleSize;

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 11: Enqueue the kernel for execution
//----------------------------------------------------- 

// Execute the kernel by using 
// clEnqueueNDRangeKernel().
// 'globalWorkSize' is the 1D dimension of the 
// work-items
status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
    cmdQueue,
    kernel,
    1,
    NULL,
    globalWorkSize,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    &someEvent);

clFinish(cmdQueue);

clGetEventProfilingInfo(someEvent, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(someEvent, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &end, NULL);

double totalTime = end - start;

printf("Total time is: %f ms \n", totalTime / 1000000.0);
//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 12: Read the output buffer back to the host
//----------------------------------------------------- 

// Use clEnqueueReadBuffer() to read the OpenCL output  
// buffer (bufferC) 
// to the host output array (C)
printf("Made it here! %i \n", status);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(
    cmdQueue,
    output,
    CL_TRUE,
    0,
    num_items,
    OutputData,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL);
printf("Made it here2! %i \n", status);


SNDFILE * outfile = sf_open("outputwavfilepathhere", SFM_WRITE, &info);
sf_count_t count = sf_write_int(outfile, OutputData, num_items);
sf_write_sync(outfile);
sf_close(outfile);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 13: Release OpenCL resources
//----------------------------------------------------- 

// Free OpenCL resources
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseCommandQueue(cmdQueue);
clReleaseMemObject(input);
clReleaseMemObject(output);
clReleaseContext(context);

// Free host resources
free(OutputData);
free(platforms);
free(devices);
free(Array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
__kernel void exchange(__global int *Array, __global int *Output)
{
    int globalSize = get_global_size(0)
    int globalId = get_global_id(0)

    for(int i = globalId; i < 1200000; i += globalSize){
        Output[i] = (Array[i]);
    }
}
```

Make sure you use the correct upper limit in the for loop. Ideally, you pass this in as another parameter.

What you were doing wrong originally, was only writing the first 100012 elements repeatedly. red up on work-item functions to get an idea of what the variables mean. [OpenCL 1.2 reference here.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/workItemFunctions.html)

Comment: The program crashes for some reason. I think the value for the loop of 1200000 is too big. I ran into that problem before, that's why I had to make two different arrays.

Comment: Also, doesn't get_global_size return 1? So can't we just add j++ instead of j+=globalSize?

Comment: I fixed a typo. 'j' should have been 'i'. Double check that your arrays are at least 1200000 long, and it shouldn't crash. The global size might be 1 for now, but when using opencl, we typically use many more work items. i+=globalSize will work for any global size.

Comment: When I try to get the sizeOf my array, it returns four, which I am assuming is the size of the the first element. So with the number of items provided by the info tag in libsndfile, I divided it by 4 and used that value instead. It compiles now. The song does play a bit longer, however it still cuts after a while and nothing is played.

Comment: clCreateBuffer expects the total size of your buffer as the third parameter. Use num_items*sizeof(int) instead of num_items. Then try using 1200000 again.

Comment: Just for your info, the num_items that I get are 1836288. When divided by 4, I get 459072. That is the value I am using in the loop now (but still does not give me the whole audio).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. So in the end it was more of a memory allocation issue than anything.